# jQuery hidden value not being sent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a certain or special of dealing with hidden fields in jQuery? I am using a hidden input field and am not receiving a value. Obviously, my code is incorrect and would be grateful if someone could show me the error. many thanks

```
<input id="customer" name="customer" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['kt_idcode_usr']; ?>" />


$('#submit').click(function () {

        var name = $('.uname').val();
        var customer = $('.customer').val();
        var department = $('#department').val();
        var email = $('.email').val();
        var position = $('.position').val();
        var feedback = $('.feedbacknew').val();
        var data = 'uname=' + name +
                   '&customer=' + customer +
                   '&department=' + department +
                   '&email=' + email +
                   '&position=' + position +
                   '&feedbacknew=' + feedback;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "feedback.php",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                $("#feedback").get(0).reset();
                $('#message').html(data);
                //$("#form").dialog('close');
                $("#flex1").flexReload();





            }
        });
        return false;

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing

```
    var customer = $('.customer').val();
```

to

```
    var customer = $('#customer').val();
```

you don't have such a class customer anywhere in this code

Comment: still blank. should i use [name=customer]?

Comment: no, that has a value. I think I traced it to id conflict. Shall try and report back. thanks

Comment: @bollo okay, so change #customer to #costumerB and change id of your input, too

Comment: changed the id to id="client" and it worked fine. I guessed earlier that there was a name conflict. Think in future I shall preifx names like: fb_customer for feed fack field etc. Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

```
$('.customer').val(); ???
```

not `.`, `#`
result

```
$('#customer').val(); // works
```

Comment: please, post a generated HTML of form.

Answer (score 2):

This line of code is wrong

```
var customer = $('.customer').val();
```

you have defined your hidden field by id, not by class, so you would need to use a # instead of a . on the selector

```
var customer = $('#customer').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

The line you have here:

```
var customer = $('.customer').val();
```

...is looking for elements with a `class` called "customer".  You don't have any such element.  You have an element with an `id` of "customer".  I suspect it will work if you simply change this line to:

```
var customer = $('#customer').val();
```

I'd suggest doing this for the rest of your input fields as well.  Generally you'll want to identify them by `id` when collecting values to submit the form.  Identifying them by `class` is typically more for things like styling different kinds of fields, binding event handlers, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

note the difference:

```
alert($('.customer').val());
```

and

```
alert($('#customer').val());
```

`.` is for classes, see http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Firstly ensure that the id's are correct, that the input tag has `id="customer"`. Secondly it must have a value, some text in the input field. the .customer example will fail, the #customer example will alert the value of the field with the id customer, provided it has a value

Answer (score 1):

I can see that for customer you are using jquery selector ".customer" which searches for an element with class name "customer" but your input has id equal to this, so:

```
var customer = $('#customer').val();
```

Answer (score 1):

may I suggest [serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)?

Comment: thanks for the heads up Itai Sagi. Will try to develop my jQuery from absolute basic to basic :-)